# How do I retain values during multiple submissions?

Tags: php, sql

I am setting up a pizza ordering website and I am trying to obtain the pizza the user selected on OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html and outputting the user's order on ShoppingCartpage.php. This works only when the user orders once, if he/she orders again then the first order gets overwritten. How do I not overwrite the first order so I can display the first order then the second order below the first order.

I have tried using PHP, POST, GET and Javascript. Buttons are not allowed on the OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html. I have included SQL code as it may be required to fix the problem.

OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Pizza Ordering Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Online Pizza Ordering Page</h1>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=supreme">
            <img src="supreme.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Supreme" 
    alt="Supreme">
        </a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=meatlover">
           <img src="meatlover.jpg" width="82" height="86" 
  title="Meatlover" alt="Meatlover">
        </a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=hawaii">
            <img src="hawaii.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Hawaii" 
    alt="Hawaii">
        </a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=fourseasons">
            <img src="fourseasons.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Four 
    Seasons" alt="Four Seasons">
       </a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=vege">
            <img src="vege.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Vege" 
    alt="Vege">
        </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

DetailedSauceandquantitypage.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Detailed sauce and quantity page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Detailed sauce and quantity page</h1>
        <form action="ShoppingCartpage.php" method="POST">
            <!-- set form value to retrieve and pass the selected pizza to 
    the cart -->
            <input type="hidden" name="pizza" value="<?php echo 
    htmlspecialchars($_GET['pizza'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); ?>">

            <img src="bbq.jpg" alt="BBQ">
            <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
            <input type="number" name="bbqPizza" min="0" max="100" 
    value="0">
            <br>
            <img src="tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato">
            <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
            <input type="number" name="tomatoPizza" min="0" max="100" 
    value="0"> 
            <br>
            <img src="salsa.jpg" alt="Salsa">
            <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
            <input type="number" name="salsaPizza" min="0" max="100" 
    value="0"> 
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="submit">
            <br>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

ShoppingCartpage.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping Cart page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Shopping Cart page</h1>
        <?php
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $bbqPizza = $tomatoPizza = $salsaPizza = "";

        if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
            $pizza = $_POST['pizza']; //value from first page
            $bbq = $_POST["bbqPizza"];
            $tomato = $_POST["tomatoPizza"];
            $salsa = $_POST["salsaPizza"];
            echo $bbq . " " . $pizza . " pizzas with bbq sauce, " . 
    $tomato . " " . $pizza . " pizzas with tomato sauce and " . $salsa . " 
     " . $pizza . " Spizzas with salsa sauce.";
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        <a href="OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html">Add more pizzas to cart</a>
        <a href="Checkoutpage.html">Go to checkout</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

pizzastore.sql

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
    -- version 4.0.10.19
    -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net
    --
    -- Host: localhost
    -- Generation Time: Apr 18, 2019 at 02:42 PM
    -- Server version: 5.1.73
    -- PHP Version: 5.3.3

    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";


    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

    --
    -- Database: `pizzastore`
    --

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `CUSTOMER`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CUSTOMER` (
      `CustID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `UserName` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `Password` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
      `GivenName` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `LastName` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `Address` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      `CreditCard` int(16) NOT NULL,
      `Email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`CustID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `CUSTOMER`
    --

    INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER` (`CustID`, `UserName`, `Password`, `GivenName`,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    `LastName`, `Address`, `CreditCard`, `Email`) VALUES
    (1000, 'AAA', '1234abcd', 'Bill', 'John', '3 First Ave, Eastwood,                         
    Sydney', 2147483647, 'b.john@wsu.edu.au'),
    (2000, 'BBB', 'abcd1234', 'Leon', 'Jack', '1 Third Road, Parramatta, 
    Sydney', 2147483647, 'l.jack@navitas.com');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `ORDER`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ORDER` (
      `OrderID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `CustID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `OrderDate` date NOT NULL,
      `OrderTime` time NOT NULL,
      `OrderStatus` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
      PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`,`CustID`),
      KEY `CustID` (`CustID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `ORDER`
    --

    INSERT INTO `ORDER` (`OrderID`, `CustID`, `OrderDate`, `OrderTime`,         
    `OrderStatus`) VALUES
    (1, 2000, '2018-01-01', '12:30:00', 'Pending'),
    (2, 2000, '2017-12-25', '17:00:00', 'Pending'),
    (3, 1000, '2018-01-02', '18:00:00', 'Pending'),
    (4, 1000, '2017-11-01', '20:00:00', 'delivered');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `ORDER_DETAILS`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ORDER_DETAILS` (
      `OrderID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `PizzaID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `SauceID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `Quantity` int(2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`,`PizzaID`,`SauceID`),
      KEY `PizzaID` (`PizzaID`),
      KEY `SauceID` (`SauceID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `ORDER_DETAILS`
    --

    INSERT INTO `ORDER_DETAILS` (`OrderID`, `PizzaID`, `SauceID`,         
    `Quantity`) VALUES
    (1, 222, 101, 2),
    (1, 333, 202, 1),
    (3, 222, 303, 2),
    (3, 555, 101, 1),
    (4, 222, 202, 3),
    (4, 444, 202, 4);

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `PIZZA`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PIZZA` (
      `PizzaID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `PizzaName` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `Price` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
      `Size` int(2) NOT NULL,
      `Picture` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PizzaID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `PIZZA`
    --

    INSERT INTO `PIZZA` (`PizzaID`, `PizzaName`, `Price`, `Size`,         
    `Picture`) VALUES
    (111, 'Supreme', '19.95', 7, 'supreme.jpg'),
    (222, 'Veggie', '15.95', 7, 'vege.jpg'),
    (333, 'Hawaii', '16.95', 7, 'hawaii.jpg'),
    (444, 'Meatlover', '19.95', 7, 'meatlover.jpg'),
    (555, 'Four seasons', '22.95', 7, 'fourseasons.jpg');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `SAUCE`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SAUCE` (
      `SauceID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `SauceName` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `SauceCost` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
      `SaucePic` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`SauceID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `SAUCE`
    --

    INSERT INTO `SAUCE` (`SauceID`, `SauceName`, `SauceCost`, `SaucePic`)                 
    VALUES
    (101, 'BBQ', '5.95', 'bbq.jpg'),
    (202, 'Hot chilli', '4.95', 'salsa.jpg'),
    (303, 'Tomato', '4.95', 'tomato.jpg');

    --
    -- Constraints for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- Constraints for table `ORDER`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `ORDER`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `ORDER_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CustID`) REFERENCES         
    `CUSTOMER` (`CustID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

    --
    -- Constraints for table `ORDER_DETAILS`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `ORDER_DETAILS`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `ORDER_DETAILS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PizzaID`)         
    REFERENCES `PIZZA` (`PizzaID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `ORDER_DETAILS_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`OrderID`)         
    REFERENCES `ORDER` (`OrderID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `ORDER_DETAILS_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`SauceID`)         
    REFERENCES `SAUCE` (`SauceID`);

    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I expect the results to be the first order outputted on ShoppingCartpage.php and the second order to be outputted below the first order. The actual result is the second order just overwrites the first order and the first order is gone.

Comment: Store the orders as an array in a session. Then you can add how many you want and output it where ever and how ever you need. You also won't need to pass the data along through your different forms.

Comment: How do I do that? I have only used an array in java before.

Comment: Google something like. _"php shopping cart session"_ and you will find many tutorials/guides/examples.

Comment: Where do I put the session code? On which page?